# my aggregrate function returming empty array with postman but when i did same with mongodbcompass it is returning documents correctly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

my post route it is showing all documents in mongodb compass but giving empty array in postman

```
router.post("/dashboard/messages", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userid = req.body.userid;
    const user = await User.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          "friendsList": userid
        }
      },
    ])
    if(user){
      res.send(user)
    }else{
      res.send({ message: "error" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching user" });
  }
});
```

mongodb compass input in aggregration is

```
{
 friendsList:ObjectId('6043100b0ca25c23d4928067')
}
```

output documents which match
e.g:
_

```
id:6043100b0ca25c23d4928067
createdAt:2021-03-06T05:11:24.044+00:00
friendsList:Array
username:"d"
email:"d@gmail.com"
password:"$2a$10$nxb2qkjbz35Ra9GW6DP3YeHAeeVni9BIB7i0yCH.qHSpVVy8xp2Ke"
__v:0
```

Postman:
input

```
{
    "userid":"6043100b0ca25c23d4928067"
}
```

outut:

```
[]
```

Comment: you have to convert string userId to obejct id, are your using mongoose npm or mongodb npm?

Comment: mongoose how to do it

Comment: convert it using `"friendsList": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)`

Comment: i did this its giving error in postman

Comment: {
    "message": "Error in Fetching user"
} this err

Comment: "$match": {
          "friendsList": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid)
        } did this

Comment: just console the `e.message` or `e` in catch block. and post message and error

Comment: mongoose is not defined

Comment: did i didnot imported mongoose

Comment: Pratik, I guess, as you are saying FriendList is an array. just to match the records, 

await User.aggregate([
      {
        "$match":  {"$expr": {"$in": [ObjectId(userId), "$friendLists"]}}
      },
    ])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code according to me will be

```
router.post('/dashboard/messages', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userid = req.body.userid;
        const user = await User.aggregate([
            { $match: { friendsList: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } },
        ]);
        if (user.length) {
            res.send(user);
        } else {
            res.send({ message: 'error' });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.send({ message: 'Error in Fetching user' });
    }
});
```

First of all you need to convert the string to objectId and then you have to use `if(user.length)` instead of `if(user)`.

Because `user` will be always will be an array. You have to check wether any data is coming in that array or not. That is why I am using `user.length` in the `if else` condition.